# Auto-implemented property in VB.NET with a protected setter?

Tags: vb.net, properties, protected

So far I had a read-only property in VB.NET as

```
Public ReadOnly Property Username() As String
```

Now I need to make changes to my code as the setter to this property needs to be protected. In C# I would have done:

```
public string Username {get; protected set;}
```

But I can't find such a short hand and good-looking solution in VB.NET. Does VB.NET provide that and I am unaware of this? Or do I have to write so much code and make it look little uglier?

```
Public Property Username() As String
    Get
        Return m_Username
    End Get
    Protected Set
        m_Username = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Username As String
```

It's going to make my class so dirty if I had 20 properties and set them like this.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no such shorthand syntax in VB.  Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties

Answer (score 1):

You could make your code a bit shorter by doing it like this:

```
Protected _username As String

Public ReadOnly Property Username As String
    Get
        Return _username
    End Get
End Property
```

That way you can set the username through _username in classes that inherit this class.

Comment: This unfortunately would not allow for additional logic in the property setter, such as for raising INotifyPropertyChanged events. A separate method dedicated for setting the value could be implemented which also handles this logic, but then the method could be declared as protected and `_username` could instead be private.

Comment: The author was asking what VB's "short hand" is for C#'s trivial property notation, there is no logic in the setter or the getter, just scoping restrictions. This answer is currently the closest you can get.